# Fading the start of a sound with Python

Tags: python, audio, fadein

I'm a student in a programming class and I just can't get this fading in to work... Right now it's just muting the first few samples of length fade_length... can anyone tell me why it does so so I can find out a way to fix it?

```
<code erased>
```

Help without direct answers would be great. Thank you

Comment: Is fade length long enough? It will have to be 44100 if you want the fade to be 1 second (assuming this is the sample rate).

Comment: yeah, i did and it completely muted the area I wanted it to fade...

Comment: In `sound.set_left(samp, int(new_left))`, is it perhaps expecting a number between 0 and 1 (where you are rounding to an int)?

Comment: it should be the left value multiplied by the factor which is between 0 and 1 so the value itself should be greater than one... but i see where you got that... I'll check and see if maybe that's partly the reason...

Comment: <code erased> ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.x, try

```
factor = 1.0 * index / fade_length
```

An `int` divided by a larger `int` is 0. You have to coerce the operation to floating point division.

Edit:

You can also use `from __future__ import division` to make the division operator use true division like Python 3. Use '//' for floor division.

Comment: Right.  You're casting it to float too late.  The order of operations is to divide and then convert to float.  You need to first convert to float and then divide.

Comment: For readability, I'd go with `factor = index / float(fade_length)`.